# mysql multi-source replication stability

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, replication, amazon-rds, database-replication

We use mysql multi-source replication, analysts and developers works with the databases, it's a main task of server(cross-bases queries, etc). Mysql slave replicates data from about 10-15 servers, some of them is realy big (400gb, 500gb, 1.5tb). Slave host - ec2 r4.2xlarge. But have some problems, main of them - stability. Often there is an errors 1236, 1594. We fix one channel - another fails, sometimes it's critical.

Backups of most master databases are performed through ebs snapshot, where datadir located. But here another problem of mysql multi-source - work with backups, unlike multi instance replication, I can not just change datadir, where backup located.

I was trying to find a solution that at least partially solved the problems of stability and work with snapshots, but I found absolutely nothing.
Did I understand correctly that there is no support for multi-source replication in the aws-RDS?

Maybe there is a similar solution, or there is another approach to solving the problem (FEDERATED is bad variant). Thanks for any help and advices.

Comment: You shouldn't be encountering these errors.  Correctly initialized replication should just work.  Errors are an indication that your initial setup is incorrect or perhaps that you are trying to use replication filtering without fully understanding the implications.  If your masters are not using `BINLOG_FORMAT` = `ROW` then you should consider it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thx, i read about it.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, you shouldn't be encountering these errors. Multi source replication has quite stable now. I personally been using it for more than 2 years now. Yes I have faced some of issues like "slave trying to access binlogs that master has purged", but most of them were easy to sort out. I would recommend you to look at these replication topics:

- [Errant transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/utils-task-slavetrx.html)
- [GTID hole](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-howto.html) : this was there because of [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71376)
- [max allowed packet error](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/08/mysql-replication-got-fatal-error-1236-causes-and-cures/)

> We fix one channel - another fails, sometimes it's critical.

make sure you're not touching GTID set for other channels.

> Did I understand correctly that there is no support for multi-source
>   replication in the aws-RDS?

The feature still not available in any of AWS cloud services. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=781416&tstart=0

Answer (score -1):

Multi source replication is not supported in RDS , you can use AWS DMS for same purpose .